# Lossy Split and Join Expression

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I'm using the `split(/ /)` method, but after I `join` them the ending white spaces are gone.

The string matched against is this:

```
"word word  word  "
```

The array returned from split(/ /) is this:

```
["word", " ", "word", " ", " ", "word"]
```

I expected this:

```
["word", " ", "word", " ", " ", "word", " ", " "]
```

Comment: Please add some details: your input string, the array after calling `split`, the string after calling `join` and the expected string.

Comment: so the string be like this:
word word  word  .
the array i got with .split(/ /) gives this:
["word", " ", "word", " ", " ", "word"]
but i looking for this:
["word", " ", "word", " ", " ", "word", " ", " "]

Comment: Thanks for providing additional details. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your example. On my system, `.split(/ /)` returns `["word", "word", "", "word"]`. Could you check your code again?

Comment: you got the correct answer. but as you see .split(/ /) ignores the two white spaces between the last word and the period.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. Please post your actual code and the actual result. Don't omit anything and feel free to revert my changes to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

```
str.scan(/\w+| /)
```

this is an example

> 2.2.1 :003 >  "word word  word ".scan(/\w+| /)
>   => ["word", " ", "word", " ", " ", "word", " "]

Comment: that's not quite what i want but close to that: 
here's the sentence:
word word  word  .
and i need an array of ["word", " ", "word", " ", " ", "word", " ", " "]
i must have those end-white spaces.